# "Object does not match target type" exception when reflecting over object properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm updating some code so that it reflects into the models it receives and figures out what properties to write out fields in a PDF file rather than me subclassing and manually mapping the fields for each and every PDF. The problem is that I can't get the property's value because of an `Object does not match target type` exception. Looking through similar questions on SO it seems like a simple fix, but just doesn't want to work. Here's my code that I'm testing through LINQPad:

```
var pdf = typeof(PdfModel2);

pdf.GetProperties().Where(
    p =>
        p.GetCustomAttribute<PdfTextFieldAttribute>() != null).Select(
    p =>
        p.GetValue(pdf)).Dump();
```

Can someone point me where I'm going wrong here? Is it because the `PdfModel2` class I'm reflecting over has properties its inheriting from a base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you don't get a value is because you are looking at the type. Properties only have values if an instance is passed to `GetValue`. So what you need to do is:

```
var pdf = new PdfModel2 { SomeProperty = "SomeValue" };
var pdfType = pdf.GetType();

pdfType.GetProperties().Where(
    p =>
        p.GetCustomAttribute<PdfTextFieldAttribute>() != null).Select(
    p =>
        p.GetValue(pdf)).Dump();
```

Comment: @DudiKeleti correct! But given the question I don't think his properties are static.

Comment: @Ric.Net you're right, I forgot that I was not working with an instance of the class at all so there wouldn't be a source of values to begin with. Classic case of late night coding, lol. Thanks for the help!